# The requested resource is not available error in java servlet login program(POST method)

Tags: java, windows, servlets, netbeans

I am trying to run this program but it dosent work.I am using net beans 8.2 with jdk 7, rest all works but i end up with this error - "The requested resource is not available" in WelcomeServlet.java.

index.html

````
```<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="FirstServlet" method="post">  
        Name:<input type="text" name="username"/><br/><br/>  
        Password:<input type="password" name="userpass"/><br/><br/>  
        <input type="submit" value="login"/>  
    </form> 
</body>
````

```

FirstServlet.java

```
package newpackage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
/**
 *
 * @author J for Jay
 */
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet FirstServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet FirstServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        String n=request.getParameter("username");  
    String p=request.getParameter("userpass");   
    if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){  
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("WelcomeServlet.java");  
        rd.forward(request,response);  
    }  
    else{  
        out.print("Sorry username or password error");  
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");  
        rd.include(request,response);  
    }      
    out.close();
    }
    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

WelcomeServlet.java

```
package newpackage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author J for Jay
 */

public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet WelcomeServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet WelcomeServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */

    //@WebServlet(name="",urlPatterns={"/"})

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
         try{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String name=request.getParameter("username");  
    out.print("Welcome "+name);  

    out.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>


}
```

LoginDao.java

```
package newpackage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author J for Jay
 */
public class LoginDao extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet LoginDao</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet LoginDao at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

    public static boolean validate(String name,String pass){  
boolean status=false;  
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bgkv?useSSL=false","root","123456");  

PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from login where username=? and password=?");  
ps.setString(1,name);  
ps.setString(2,pass); 


ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
status=rs.next();  

}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
return status;  
}  
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>newpackage.FirstServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginDao</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>newpackage.LoginDao</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>newpackage.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FirstServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginDao</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginDao</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WelcomeServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

I am using NetBeans 8.2 with jdk 7, database is already created, sql connetor.jar is also added.

Comment: Instead of `WelcomeServlet.java` simply write `WelcomeServlet` and check if that works .i.e: `RequestDispatcher rd=...("WelcomeServlet");`

Comment: Dude thank you so much. i tried that before but didn't worked but i tried it now again it worked. again thanks